# pass deluge torrentname to powershell via bat script

Tags: powershell, batch-file, torrent

I've install deluge and would like to use the execute plugin to send a pushover message via powershell

```
set torrentname=%2
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Pushover-DelugeNotify.ps1 %torrentname%
```

I've created the above yet for some reason it doesn't work I see a cmd window flash up and close, yet no message comes through.

I've tried

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Pushover-DelugeNotify.ps1 "Test"
```

which works no problem.

whay am I doing wrong?

Comment: When running the (1st) batch file do you also pass 2 arguments (the 2nd to be "Test") to it? E.g.: `"%YOUR_1ST_BATCH_FILE%" "ApparentlySomeUnusedArg" "Test"`.

Comment: Sorry I meant is when I use the command with "test" I get the pushover message

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have other arguments on your batch, you should use "set torrentname=%1"

```
set torrentname=%1
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File C:\Pushover-DelugeNotify.ps1 %torrentname%
```

Comment: I tried that but I looks like deluge won't run the script I see the cmd Windows yet nothing happens